# How can i check the state of toggle button for wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi, togglebutton, onresume

In my application i have a toggle button that needs to activate or disable the wifi.

```
    public void getRisparmio(View view) {
    // is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    if (on) {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } else {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
    }
```

Now the problem is: if the wifi is already activated and I launch the app, the toggle button should be pressed/activated. Actually doesn't go and the toggle always resume its state on off. I think i can check the state `onResume()` but i don't know how and i don't know if i have to add something in the `onCreate()` method too.

How can i do to check the state? Thanks

Comment: Are you listening for change in the wifi state and toggling change of button state?

Comment: The code is which i posted. Actually when i click the toggle goes in on state and the wifi turns on, click again and the wifi turns off. The application goes well but there is the problem i wrote. The state of the toggle button needs to be according to the state the wifi is in when i open the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set the toggle button in onCreate() and onResume() using the toggle button's method as such:

```
toggleButton.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
```

E.g.

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() 
{ 
    super.onResume();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggleButton.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()); 
}
```

Comment: something like:   `@Override`
    `protected void onResume() {`
        `super.onResume();`
         `toggleButton.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());`
    `}`  ?

Comment: you will have to redeclare the variables, but in essence yes.

Comment: mmh, "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method isWifiEnabled() from the type WifiManager."  But `isWifiEnabled()` from where you take it?

Comment: what's ur id for togglebutton?

Comment: it's toggleButton1.. I think your method is correct but i don't know i have this error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setChecked(boolean) from the type ToggleButton."

Comment: Yeah, we may miscommunicate with each other since the variable names are same as their respective class names, I'll redo with this new info.

Comment: have i to create a local variable? And set it `null`?

Comment: Ok, no errors `onResume()` butin the `onCreate()` i get this one : "wifiManager cannot be resolved" and ask me to create a variable. Have i to write everything that is inside in the `onResume()` in the `onCreate()`? or only `toggleButton.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());` ?

Comment: Yes, rewrite the whole bit in oncreate